# How to resolve merge conflict in a git Pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have done some coding in a feature branch (say fbranch) and have created a pull request for review. I noticed that the pull request was showing a merge conflict for one file, say Test.java. So I did the following--

git checkout master (switched to main branch)

git pull

Then --

git checkout fbranch

git merge master

As expected, i got a merge conflict while doing merge,

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in osd-service-Test.java
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I manually resolved the conflicts and then did --

git add Test.java

git commit -m "Resolving the merge conflict"

git push

Now i went and checked the Pull request in bitbucket. The merge conflict got resolved but now im also seeing few other files that got modified which was not part of my changes. These changes happened while I did the git merge and these were changes done by another developer.

But I want my Pull Request to only show the files that i modified and not the other changes. Is that possible?

Comment: You probably want to do a `git rebase master fbranch`. If you did not share your branch with anybody else, that "rewriting history" should no be a problem.

Comment: Note: you tagged this with both [tag:github] and [tag:bitbucket], but pull requests are add-ons, and GitHub and Bitbucket have little details (that still matter) that differ between how they handle their PRs, so you should limit the tags here. I've stripped out the GitHub one.

Answer (score 0):

PRs from bitbucket offers a commit section where the reviewers can identify your work/which commits relates to the merge actions.

Rebase option might offer you a clean history based on your feature work but it should be used with caution.

More details on merge vs rebase: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing